# A person looking for a place to stay the night - is it accommodations

Tags: word-choice

Given this fragment: "Can't find accommodation in Mantova, Italy."
Assume it is a single person looking for a place to spend the night.

Would the correct word be "accommodation" or "accommodations"? While [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accommodation) does list *accommodation* as a mass noun, it also has a count example:

> Lodgings, sometimes also including board:
>   *the company offers a number of guest house accommodations in Oberammergau*

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you! You have NO idea how nervous I was thinking about posting a question here...

Comment: I was all ready to close this summarily as General Reference with that link as the reference, and found that it's not as clear-cut as I thought it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following source  the BrE 'accommodation' is an unaccountable noun and the AmE *accommodations* is a plural noun.

[BrE Accommodation vs AmE Accommodations](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Accomodation): (Usage)

> - Accommodation is where you live or stay, especially when you are on holiday or when you are staying somewhere for a short amount of time. In British English, accommodation is an uncountable noun. *Don't talk about 'accommodations' or 'an accommodation'*.
>
>   - There is plenty of student accommodation in Edinburgh.
>       We booked our flights and accommodation three months before our holiday.
>       **Speakers of American English usually talk about accommodations.**
>   - The hotel provides cheap accommodations and good food.
>       Be Careful!
>       Don't talk about *'an accommodation'* in either British English or American English. Don't say, for example, 'I'm looking for an accommodation near the city centre'. Say 'I'm looking for accommodation near the city centre' or in American English, 'I'm looking for accommodations near the city centre'.

Collins COBUILD English Usage ©

Comment: OK, I think I understand. This started when I edited a question (s & g) and changed the words to "accommodations" along with other edits. Less than a minute later, someone came in behind me  and did another edit back to "accommodation". As an American English speaker, the one with the 's' sounds more correct to my 'ears' but I've left it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that the ODO example of it as a mass noun is only typical of British usage. I've never heard the singular used that way in American English. I checked a couple of American dictionaries and did not see a similar example. You would be safest to say "accomodations" whether it is just one person or a group requiring multiple rooms and meals.